# Error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library" version 16 ...? Also possible to make it work on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

So I've written a small console application in C# that will crawl the entire target SharePoint site and display users & rights, but it's now displaying the following error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is on my own local development PC with no SharePoints installed however.

Here's the code of the small console application :

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RightsDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://test.sharepoint.com"))
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
                    ShowAssignments(web.RoleAssignments);
                    foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
                        ShowAssignments(list.RoleAssignments);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void ShowAssignments(SPRoleAssignmentCollection rolesAss)
        {
            foreach (SPRoleAssignment ass in rolesAss)
            {
                if (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"   {ass.Member.LoginName}");
                    foreach (SPRoleDefinition item in ass.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"            {item.Name}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also could I make this somehow work on a SharePoint Online target Site? Do I also require the DLLs then? Is there an easy way to display all users & rights across all sites, lists, etc... in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

The serverside code you have written needs to be executed on a SharePoint server. In that environment, you'll have access to all the dlls needed. My recommendation is to instead use a clientside approach.

You mentioned that you need to target SharePoint Online. Download [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=35585) and use PowerShell to get the information you want. The SDK will give you the dlls needed. Then you can refer to [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-sharepoint-site-groups-and-users/) article on how to get the users.